# Remove outliers before aggregate in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with 5 columns. I groupby the first 4 columns and calculate the mean, std and count of the 5th column.

I do this with the following code:

```
df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3','col4']).agg([np.mean, np.std, len])
```

Now my question, I have a function which replace the outliers with the mean value. How can I just drop those rows that are outliers?

```
def replace(group):
    mean, std = group.mean(), group.std()
    outliers = (group - mean).abs() > 3*std
    group[outliers] = mean        
    return group

    df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3','col4']).transform(replace)
```

Second question,

When I try to combine both transform and agg, I have the following error:

```
df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3','col4']).transform(replace).agg([np.mean, np.std, len])

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'agg'
```

Comment: I think you can use `df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3','col4']).apply(replace)` instead `df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3','col4']).transform(replace)`

Comment: The error is clear you're returning the result of the initial `transform` and calling `agg` on this, `agg` only works on `groupby` objects. For your first step could you not just assign `True/False` when the values are outliers and then just filter them as a post-processing step?

Comment: @EdChum Will this work `group.drop(group[outliers],inplace=True)`

Comment: No, `drop` here looks at row labels, if you did that it would probably raise a `ValueError` what you want is to add the outliers indicator column and then filter the df `df[df['outliers'] == True]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`transform()` returns a `DataFrame` which has not `agg()` method, you need to call `groupby()` method again. Or you can save the groupby object, and reuse it's `grouper` attribute.

To drop outliers, you need call `apply()` and get a boolean series `mask`, and then select the rows, and call `groupby()` again.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(N, 4)), columns=["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"])
df["c5"] = np.random.randn(N)

def replace(group):
    mean, std = group.mean(), group.std()
    inliers = (group - mean).abs() <= 2*std
    return group.where(inliers, mean)

def drop(group):
    mean, std = group.mean(), group.std()
    inliers = (group - mean).abs() <= 2*std
    return inliers

g = df.groupby(['c1','c2','c3','c4'])

s1 = g.c5.transform(replace)
res1 = s1.groupby(g.grouper).agg([np.mean, np.std, len])

mask = g.c5.apply(drop)
res2 = df[mask].groupby(['c1','c2','c3','c4']).c5.agg([np.mean, np.std, len])
```

You can also calculate the agg in callback function:

```
def func(group):
    mean, std = group.mean(), group.std()
    inliers = (group - mean).abs() <= 2*std
    tmp = group[inliers]
    return {"mean":tmp.mean(), "std":tmp.std(), "len":tmp.shape[0]}

g.c5.apply(func).unstack()
```